# PHP/JSON methods of obtaining FB Line count for a given URL - not a Facebook page

Tags: php, json, facebook

There used to be a really good way of polling for the number of Facebook likes than a particular URL had got: [http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode('https://www.ns.nl')](http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=%22.urlencode(%27https://www.ns.nl%27))

I program in PHP and the great thing about this method was that you could use JSON and find out the FB Like count for a given URL. I hadn't used this for a year or two but now I've come back to it, the response now says: "error_msg":"REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher (12)

Any ideas what should I be using instead?

Please note that somebody closed this question with "This question already has answers here:
Graph API how get facebook page members/likes (3 answers)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

I am NOT asking how to get likes of a Facebook page - that is more straightforward. I am asking how to get total likes of a URL when shared to Facebook. E.g [www.ns.nl](http://www.ns.nl) is shared to a page (7 likes) then to somebody's timeline (4 likes) then to a group (2 likes). So 13 likes in total for the URL.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/url, `engagement` field.

Comment: From this advice, I tried the following (declaration section):

require 'facebook.php';

$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '{appid}',
  'secret' => '{appsecret}',
    'fileUpload' => true     // this is important !
));

Comment: Code section:
    try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '?id=https://www.ns.nl&fields=engagement','{access_token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
/* handle the result */

Comment: Response was: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument.

Token, secret and appID all valid - app is posting to FB pages with no issues

Comment: Sorry for formatting of above - I was trying to find out how to add code here when it didn't show properly  but then the ability to edit it ran out

Comment: The SDK calculates the app-secret proof automatically, so likely something must be wrong with your setup or the parameters you are passing then.

Comment: Graph API Explorer is a GUI tool to help _test_ requests. But it is not the actual API, you need to make your request to the latter.

Comment: `$rest_url = "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fids=".urlencode($url);`

Comment: I'm asking for help what to replace the above line of code with. I just really want the replacement for the restserver call from the original comment. I feel I'm getting bogged down in the Graph API explorer. Hint: I'm really lost!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview explains the basics, such as what host name to use.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough in reading Facebook manuals to make sense of what I see in the documentation. I'm really after:
`http://<what do I put here?>&url=www.saab.se`
I can see from the graph explorer that I will get back [share_count][reaction_count][comment_count] but how do I make the JSON call successfully in this one case not in the graph explorer?

Comment: If there is no more <what do I put here> answer any more, I'll be satisfied with that - I'll hire a programmer. I was hoping it was a copy/paste job to replace the restserver.php line

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&access_token=…`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: Thanks @CBroe - that was it - just a note that the user needs "&fields=engagement" before the access token